# Apostrophe in FULL TEXT SEARCH mysql

Tags: mysql, database, full-text-search, apostrophe

When I searched for citroen in search page like that I get result but if I search blackn roll I dont get result because it's written like black'n roll in the table. Some user may also wanna search blackn roll but doesnt get result. How can I fix it? And also rows like v-hr and speacial characters like "&/(). I want the mysql to ignore them.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM arac 
        INNER JOIN suv_marka ON arac.marka = suv_marka.id 
        WHERE match(suv_marka.marka) against('citroen')";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the characters (to be replaced) already then, you can use MySQL's `REPLACE` function to replace them with `%` and perform `LIKE` comparison, e.g.:

```
create table test(value varchar(100));
insert into test values ('black''n roll');


SELECT value 
FROM test 
WHERE 'blackn roll' LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(value, '''', '%'), '%');
```

You can replace 'blackn roll' with your input string and use nested `REPLACE` functions if you need to replace more than one character.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it returning both results then? Some user may search blackn roll, some user may search black'n roll. So can I get the same result?

Comment: Yes, it will return result in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

The back-slash is MySQL's escape character.  You can try the following...  Full text indexing gets a little weird because of word terminators.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM arac 
        INNER JOIN suv_marka ON arac.marka = suv_marka.id 
        WHERE match(suv_marka.marka) against ('black\'n roll' IN BOOLEAN MODE);"
```

If that doesn't work, then try looking for the words individually.  Word length is also a factor, small words (less than 4 characters by default) are not indexed.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM arac 
        INNER JOIN suv_marka ON arac.marka = suv_marka.id 
        WHERE match(suv_marka.marka) against ('black' + 'roll' IN BOOLEAN MODE);"
```